# HTTP 505 error when requesting Heroku apps w a cell module

Tags: http, heroku, at-command, iot, modem

I'm trying to use the Telit GE910 cell module to make HTTP requests over the cell network. I've connected it via a FTDI board to my computer's USB port and am sending it AT commands via the terminal. I'm using the AT commands to successfully open a socket in command mode and send the HTTP request.

```
AT#SD=1,0,80,"google.com",0,0,1
OK
�AT#SSEND=1
> HE�AD� /� HTT�P/1.1


OK

SRING: 1
```

I don't understand why these � are turning up. When making requests for google.com this is fine but anything hosted on Heroku gives me a 505 error.

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 20:39:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I've read in one or two forums that this 505 response is specific to Heroku and has to do with incorrect spacing in the HTTP request. I suspect the unrecognized characters are creating the problem. What is going on? They consistently turn up before 'A', 'space', and 'P'; there may be other letters also but those are the ones that I've seen.

Comment: Btw, I can successfully make HTTP requests to my Heroku web server using cURL, WiFi clients built on the ESP8266 wifi module, and the TCP Client built for the LinkIt ONE IoT dev board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out (I think) why I was getting a 505 response. Then I started getting a 400, but I figured that out too!

In the application note for socket dials from Nimbelink (which is a vendor that uses the Telit cell modules--I have one of their modules which has the Telit GE910 on it) it says that after you enter your HTTP request (e.g. `GET / HTTP/1.1`) you're meant to hit **ctrl+j** twice to signal the end of the request.

Well, I started doing all of my serial communication in CoolTerm so that I could see the HEX I was sending. (My hope was I could catch the � characters--I didn't, in fact they don't turn up in CoolTerm.) **ctrl+j** results in a single line feed (HEX: 0A). According to HTTP documentation, to signal the end of a line you're meant to use carriage return line feed (HEX: 0D 0A). ([Heroku also says it has to be formatted like this.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#not-supported)) This is what I send when I hit **enter**. So if I end `GET / HTTP/1.1` with **enter** twice, the request gets though. Though even a `HEAD / HTTP/1.1` request to heroku.com comes back as a 400. But that's up next:

According to RFC (which I found out [here](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1106)) HTTP 1.1 requires a Host. So if I do the whole thing with the right line endings

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: heroku.com
```

it works! It also works for posting to my server.